# How to line-up a popup menu with a button

Tags: user-interface, delphi, popup, position

I came up with the problem of having a popup menu, triggered by a button, to be close to the button that triggered it.

My solution looks like this:

```
procedure TfLoadEntrySSP.cxBbtnPrintOutClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Sender as TcxButton do begin
    pmReport.Popup(left, ClientToScreen(Point(left,top)).y+height+5) ;
  end;
end;
```

This will display the menu left aligned with the button starting 5px below the button.

Maybe there are other people having the same problem and need a quick and simple fix. I hope this could help in such a case.

Comment: What will happen when the button is near the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I think your question is actually an answer to an unasked question.

Comment: Well, that wasn't my problem but of course, you have to deal with that if you wan't it to be totally generic. My problem was to position the menu related to the button. If my button has been at the bottom of my form I probably changed the position to be above and to the right or left of the bottom. So you have to deal with that case for case. But that would be a more obvious and easy problem to solve.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout AFAIK `Popup` handles this fine without developer intervention.

Comment: @larand StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a general knowledge sharing site, like a forum. If you have something you want to share to the community, post it in the form of a question, and then post an answer for it.

Comment: This is a question and answer site, which means that before you can post an answer you must first ask a question. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Ok, I understand. I was thinking about doing it as you say but I was unsure and choose the wrong way. Now I know how to do it.